# Creating Multiple Links in an Access Textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a form in Access 2016 with a textbox in which I need to have multiple, semi-colon delimited hyperlinks (which will be dynamically created).  What I've decided to do is create a "hyperlink construction string" in VBA, then assign them to the value of the textbox.  So, something like:

```
Me.Field.Value = {link: www.google.com : "Google"} & "; " & {link: www.yahoo.com : "Yahoo"}
```

...would result in this being in the text box:

[Google](http://www.google.com); [Yahoo](http://www.yahoo.com)

My problem is, I can't seem to figure out the syntax to create an individual link in the textbox without making the entire textbox a single hyperlink, which isn't gonna work.

I was working with a few solutions that I've found.  I read that this would create the link in the way I need, but it just comes through as literal text with the pound signs:

```
"Google # www.google.com # Some Argument"
```

I also tried setting the textbox to rich text, then setting the value to include rich text code for a hyperlink... but that's not working:

```
"{\field{\*\fldinst HYPERLINK ""http://www.google.com/""}{\fldrslt http://www.google.com}}"
```

I also thought about designing a Query that will return the hyperlinks.  But, I kind of wanted to make it a VBA thing, because I'll have more flexibility in how I create the value.  Does anyone have any ideas?

**Note:** I understand that multiple values should be in a 1:M relational database.  They are.  But, the requirements of the task are to get all the M values for a 1 entity, then list them out in semi-colon, delimited fashion, which all serve as links to a Details table for the M entity.

Comment: YAY!  I got an upvote!  I feel all legit now.

Answer (score 1):

Regular textboxes (text only) don't support this.

It is possible with Rich text textboxes. In contrast to the name, they actually use a subset of **HTML**, not RTF.

With ideas from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/620f28de-b08a-4e58-b7c1-ad95b0fb5fee/rich-text-hyperlinks-in-textbox-control-not-working-in-access-2010?forum=accessdev) I got this working:

```
Private Sub cmdInsertHyperlinks_Click()

    Dim url1 As String, url2 As String

    url1 = "D:\tmp\test.jpg"
    url2 = "D:\tmp\test space.txt"

    Me.rText.Value = "<div>" & _
        "<a href = " & url1 & ">file://" & url1 & "</a>" & _
        "  other text between hyperlinks  " & _
        "<a href = " & url2 & ">file://" & url2 & "</a>" & _
        "</div>"


End Sub
```

Note: the linked thread says you must URL-encode the links (space to %20 etc), but at least for my simple test, that wasn't necessary.

Note 2: You can't have a different display text and link url, at least I didn't get that to work.

Comment: When you say "rich text textboxes," do you mean a standard textbox set to Rich Text?  I don't see a control called "Rich Text Textbox."  What about a List Box?  Is there a way to list the links in a dynamically growing List Box?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. A list box would be a completely different thing, there you can add items dynamically and react to click events of separate items.

Comment: Actually, the div and a tags don't really make any difference.  If you just set the value to "file://D:\tmp\test.jpg" without the div and a tags, it'll create the link just the same.

Comment: @Hill, thank you very much--adding file:// at the beginning of the filename did exactly what I needed.